# How to access xpath with index number in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I just want to access a xpath. But when I'm search this in inspect menu it finding 5 result. I want to access one of them not 5. How can I do it with index number? like...

```
xpath = "//a[@role='button']" # 5 elements available with this xpath
modified_xpath = "//a[@role='button'][2]" # I'm trying with the index number.
driver.find_element_by_xpath(modified_xpath).click() # But It's not working.
```

It's not working!

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list, remove the index lookup in the xpath and index into the returned list? `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(modified_xpath)[2]`

Comment: What is the error ? Share HTML or URL of the page

Comment: showing this error`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@role='button'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[@role='button']' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this code--

```
    xpath = "//a[@role='button']" 
    xpaths = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    xpaths[2].click()
```

Hope it will work.